# Mathematical formula terms in Scala

Tags: scala, naming-conventions

Our application relies on lots of equations, which, to correspond with the standard scientific names, use variable names like `mu_k`, (if the standard is $\mu_k$).  (We could debate whether scientists should switch to CS style descriptive variable names, but often the terms don't really *describe* anything, they are just part of equations, and, more over, we need our code to match the known literature.)

In C this is easy to name vars this way: `int mu_k`.  We are considering porting our code to Scala, but I know that `val mu_k` is discouraged in Scala, because underscores have special meanings.

1. If we use underscores only in the *middle* of the var name (e.g. `mu_k`) and not beginning or end (e.g. `_x` or `x_`), will this present a problem in Scala?
2. What is the recommended naming convention for Scala in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that underscores are discouraged in variable names in Scala, which implies that they are not forbidden. In my opinion, a convention should be followed wherever sensible.

In the case of mathematical formulae, I disagree that the Greek letters don't convey a meaning; the meaning is not necessarily intuitively descriptive for non-mathematicians, but as you say, the reference to the usage in a paper may be meaningful and important. Therefore, sticking with the underscore won't hurt, although I would probably prefer a more Scala-style way as `muX` when possible and meaningful. If you want a perfect answer, you might need to perform a usability test with your developers. In the specific example, I personally find `mu_x` more readable than `muX`, but that might differ among individuals.

I don't think the Scala compiler has a problem with underscores in the examples you described. Presumably, even leading and trailing underscores are fine, but should indeed be avoided strictly because they have a special meaning: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#methods.

Answer (score 2):

Underscores are *not* special in any way in identifiers. There are a lot of special meanings for the underscore in Scala, but not in identifiers. (There is a special *rule* in identifiers that if you want to mix alphanumeric characters and operator characters in the same identifier, they have to be separated by an underscore, e.g. `foo?` is not a legal identifier, but `foo_?` is.)

So, there is no problem using an identifier with an underscore in it.

It is generally preferred to use camelCase and PascalCase for alphanumeric identifiers, and not mix alphanumeric and operator characters in the same identifier (i.e. use `maxBy` instead of `max_by` and use `isFoo` instead of `foo_?`) but that's just a coding convention whose purpose is to reduce the number of "unspecial" underscores, so that you can quickly scan for the "special" ones.

But in your case, you are using special naming conventions anyway, so you don't need to adhere to the community naming conventions as strictly.

However, I personally would actually prefer the name `µ_k` over `mu_k`.

That's as far as it goes with Scala, unfortunately. The Fortress programming language by Sun/Oracle did allow boldface, overstrike, superscripts and subscripts in identifier names, so something like µ<sub>k</sub> would have been possible as a legal identifier, but sadly, Fortress was abandoned a couple of years ago.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not stating this is the correct way, and myself would be rather **discouraged** to do this, but you can use full string literals as identifiers:

From: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html

> id  ::=  plainid
>              |  ‘`’ stringLiteral ‘`’
>
> Finally, an identifier may also be formed by an arbitrary string
>   between back-quotes (host systems may impose some restrictions on
>   which strings are legal for identifiers). The identifier then is
>   composed of all characters excluding the backquotes themselves.

So this is valid:

`val ’mu k‘`

*(sorry, for formatting)*